# GUI apps don't inherit PATH from parent console apps

Tags: shell, gnome, gui

In Gnome, don't GUI applications inherit the `PATH` of the shell process that launches them? Apparently, GUI applications see only the `PATH` specified in `~/.profile`. No issues with console applications, though.

If I launch GUI applications available in the current `PATH` from my Bash sessions, then they fail to start.  For example:

- Thunderbird can't find the `libxpcom.so` library (it is in its folder). However, the `which` command finds that library (because the folder is in `PATH`).
- Firefox fails with *"Could not find the Mozilla runtime."*

Adding `PATH` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't fix the issue.

However, if I either:

1. set the `PATH` in `~/.profile` and restart the Gnome session;
2. or switch to an application's folder before launching it;

then I can run any GUI application from my Bash session with no problem. Indeed, at the moment I have resorted to using a script that emulates the second procedure.

What's the problem? Should I use a launcher for GUI applications, maybe?

I don't want to put my custom `PATH` in `~/.profile`, hence this question.

Thanks for your attention.

Environment:

- Debian GNU/Linux: 6.0.7
- Gnome Version: 2.30.2

**Edit**:
I don't know how Gnome is started: I installed Debian with GUI and it launches Gnome by default after a graphical login screen.

Bash is started from the Gnome Panel with the command "gnome-terminal --full-screen".

**Edit 2:**

Thanks to Bob's suggestion, I have tried running `bash --norc` - that is: Bash with the default configuration - and then adding the path to both Thunderbird and Firefox by hand and - gasp! - now both applications launch fine.  How can I troubleshoot this problem?  My `~/.bashrc` is just a bunch of addition to `PATH`.  Furthermore, the `which` command resolves both `firefox` and `thunderbird` fine. Maybe there are libraries that hide each other in my `PATH`?  In any case, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is always empty.

I think that a solution could be to have a launcher script for each GUI application, like a commenter has suggested.

Comment: Could you clarify, how you started bash and gnome? Are you running a login or non-login shell? (these terms are described here): http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html. Cause, if you're running gnome directly from gdm, not via startx it depends on gdm, whether it reads or not PATH from /etc/profile.

Comment: @Bob: I have added clarifications.  I don't know about Gnome, but I think that I'm running a login shell (at least, it reads ~/.bashrc).  However, my problem is not that Gnome doesn't read a profile script (though in my case I know it does); my problem is that GUI applications fail during startup when launched from Bash, even when PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are properly set.  Thanks.

Comment: Just for reference, if it reads `.bashrc` it is an interactive, non-login shell. See `man bash`, section "Invocation".

Comment: @Elena As far as I can judge, your problem is not related to PATH or export of environment variables by different kinds of shell. If you type "echo $PATH" in your gnome virtual terminal, running bash, and that PATH is correct, then all the gui programs will see it. I believe, you have 2 separate problems with wrong installation of Firefox and Thunerbird: /usr/bin/firefox is usually a bash script, so just find the "Could not find the Mozilla runtime." phrase within it to diagnose the problem. As for the Thunderbird, I didn't understand the logic of your experiments with it, sorry.

Comment: @Elena Anyways, could you supply the results of `echo $PATH` without and with `PATH` modified in `~/.profile`? Could you also specify the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in both cases? (just to properly document your actions, so that we could clearly understand/reproduce). Thanks.

Comment: @Bob: Thanks. The logic of my experiments is that I'm trying to keep all of my bleeding-edge applications separate from the system, because in the past I've run into problems for having added bleeding-edge applications to my `PATH` in `~/.profile`.  For instance, Synaptic failed to start because it found a more recent version of Python.  I just want the ability to run bleeding-edge GUI applications without messing up the system, that's it.

Comment: @Bob: **IMPORTANT!** I've tried to run `bash --norc` with a clean `PATH` and the problem is gone.  I've edited my question to add details (please see "Edit 2").

Comment: @Elena Could it be a typo error in addition to $PATH, you specify in your ~/.bashrc? Could you все-таки print your `$PATH` values in cases of `bash` and `bash --norc` invocations? :)

Answer (score 1):

Much of the confusion about this is because it varies by Linux distribution. In general...

- /etc/profile is sourced only on boot.
- /etc/profile sources /etc/profile.local if it exists.
- /root/.bashrc is sourced...

  - On boot, after /etc/profile.
  - On opening a new terminal session.
- Only commands entered on a terminal session command line will make use of the **PATH** set in /root/.bashrc.
- Scripts and programs executed by a GUI like Gnome use the **PATH** set in /etc/profile.
- Since /etc/profile executes /etc/profile.local if it exists, then changes and additions to **PATH** are usually best done there. Remember to 'export PATH' so all subshells see it.

I know this to be the behavior on Puppy Linux 5.2.8 Lupu which is based on Ubuntu 10.04 and research indicates it is common, at least for many Debian-based distros like Ubuntu.

You would think that a PATH set in $HOME/.profile (user script analogous to /etc/profile system-wide script) would work for non-terminal sessions like Gnome but it doesn't. The Xwindows GUI and various display managers, etc. like Gnome run parallel to terminal sessions so do not inherit $HOME/.bashrc settings.

It seems that most every program takes responsibility for resetting PATH if necessary. The following command will reveal literally dozens or even hundreds of files containing 'PATH='...

```
grep -r 'PATH=' /etc/*
```

**Illustration of relevancy to the question**

The current process hierarchy on my machine is shown below in the edited output from the command...

```
ps -efH | cut -c49-126
----------------------
/bin/busybox init
  /bin/sh /usr/bin/xwin
    /usr/bin/xinit /root/.xinitrc -- -br -nolisten tcp
      X :0 -br -nolisten tcp
      openbox
        /bin/ash /sbin/pup_event_frontend_d
          sleep 2
  /usr/local/apps/ROX-Filer/ROX-Filer -p /root/Choices/ROX-Filer/PuppyPin
    roxterm
      gnome-pty-helper
      -sh
      -sh
      -sh
      -sh
      -sh
      -sh
        ps-FULL -efH
        cut -c49-126
    geany
```

- The first line of the output would be just 'init' on most systems but
  Puppy replaces many comands like this with 'busybox'.
- Note that 'xwin', which starts the Xwindows subsystem, is run by 'init'.
- Moving down, note that ROX-Filer is functioning as the desktop manager and is at the same level as 'xwin' with 'roxterm' being the analog to 'gnome-terminal' and the '-sh' processes being the several bash terminal sessions I have open in its tabs.
- Geany is the GUI editor that's running which is also at the same level as Xwin and ROX-Filer.

Exported environment variables like PATH are only inherited from the process that launched them (e.g. their "parent process"). The ps output doesn't show it, but /etc/profile (and /etc/profile.local) is one of the many scripts read during the 'init' startup process so 'xwin' can see the PATH set in it. However, since .bashrc is *not* one of those scripts, the PATH set there cannot be seen by other GUI programs.

GUI programs *would* be able to see the .bashrc PATH if you started them from a bash commandline.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, but it is unrelated to my question.  I already know the difference between `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`, as I have explained.  The issue here is that GUI applications started from Gnome Terminal - that is: a GUI console - do not inherit their parent's `PATH`.  Such GUI applications won't start properly unless  `PATH` has been set in `~/.profile`, because of the reasons that you have listed.  However, I don't want to configure `PATH` from `~/.profile`, because it could interfere with GUI apps that expect their environment as it is shipped by Debian.